# Есть ли возможность в Postgres конкатенировать строки для вызова таблицы

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql

Всем привет, есть необходимость динамически задавать название для таблицы в sql-запросе, так как она меняет свое название каждый месяц

Например нужны данные их таблицы `table_name_05_2023`

Код возвращает только результат конкатенации:

```
SELECT * FROM CONCAT('table_name_', to_char(now(), 'MM_YYYY'))
```

Есть ли возможность реализовать без использования других языков программирования или сторонних инструментов?

База PostgreSQL

Comment: А вы пробовали так сделать, как в примере? Какие ошибки?

Comment: Ошибок нет, но возвращает просто строку table_name_05_2023

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/633328/how-can-i-access-a-postgres-table-by-name

Comment: Видимо с посощью `EXECUTE`

Comment: да, только с помощью execute. А вообще у вас не правильная структура БД. не надо на каждый месяц создавать новые таблицы. Надо сделать одну таблицу и добавить в нее колонку с датой. SQL не предназначен для работы в таком режиме как вы его решили использовать.